# Python CreateFile Cannot Find PhysicalMemory

Tags: python, memory, ctypes, createfile

I am trying to access the Physical Memory of a Windows 2000 system (trying to do this without a memory dumping tool).  My understanding is that I need to do this using the CreateFile function to create a handle.  I have used an older version of [win32dd](http://www.msuiche.net/2008/06/14/capture-memory-under-win2k3-or-vista-with-win32dd/) to help me through this.  Other documentation on the web points me to using either "\Device\PhysicalMemory" or "\\.\PhysicalMemory".  Unfortunately, I get the same error for each.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testHandles.py", line 101, in (module)
   File "testHandles.py", line 72, in createFileHandle
pywintypes.error: (3, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the path specified.')
```

Actually, the error number returned is different for each run \\.\PhysicalMemory == 3 and \Device\PhysicalMemory == 2.  Review of pywin32, win32file, createfile, pyhandle, and pywintypes did not produce information as to the different return values.

Here is my code.  I am using py2exe to get this working on Windows 2000 (and yes it compiles successfully).  I realize that I might also have a problem with DeviceIoControl but right now I am concentrating on CreateFile.

```
# testHandles.py

import ctypes
import socket
import struct
import sys
import win32file
import pywintypes

def createFileHandle():

    outLoc = pywintypes.Unicode("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\pymemdump_dotPM.dd")
    handleLoc = pywintypes.Unicode("\\\\.\\PhysicalMemory")
    #handleLoc = pywintypes.Unicode("\\Device\\PhysicalMemory")
    placeHolder = 0
    BytesReturned = 0


    # Device =                                              CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\win32dd", GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    #                                                           CreateFile(fileName,                        desiredAccess ,          shareMode ,    attributes , creationDisposition ,      flagsAndAttributes ,                    hTemplateFile )
    #hMemHandle = win32file.CreateFile(handleLoc, GENERIC_ALL, SHARE_READ, None, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
    hMemHandle = win32file.CreateFile(handleLoc, win32file.GENERIC_READ, win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
    print "hMemHandle: %s" % hMemHandle
    if (hMemHandle == NO_ERROR):
        print "Could not build hMemHandle"
        sys.exit()

    # We send destination path to the driver.
    #if (!DeviceIoControl(hMemHandle, 0x19880922, outLoc, (ULONG)(wcslen(outLoc) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR), NULL, 0, &BytesReturned, NULL))
    if (ctypes.windll.Kernel32.DeviceIoControl(hMemHandle, 0x19880922, outLoc, 5, NULL, 0, BytesReturned, NULL)):
        print "Error: DeviceIoControl(), Cannot send IOCTL.\n"
    else:
        print "[win32dd] Physical memory dumped. You can now check %s.\n" % outLoc

# Dump memory
createFileHandle()
```

Thank you,
Cutaway

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to access the physical memory object from user mode land in Windows. As your [win32dd link](http://www.msuiche.net/2008/06/14/capture-memory-under-win2k3-or-vista-with-win32dd/) suggests, you will need to do it from kernel mode.

Comment: The method I use here (once working) should be okay for everything pre-XPSP2 as it allows Physical Memory access from usermode land.  You are correct, everything else XPSP2 and greater, will require kernel mode and is most likely not possible using Python.

Thank you,
Cutawa

Comment: Ah, a little more digging and you appear to be correct. Though I would expect you would at the very least need to be running as an administrator to get this working. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: I don't believe "Administrator" privilege is necessary but I could be wrong.  I am running as this user on my test box.

Comment: Well I don't know for certain if it is required, but I do know that it has always been required for \\.\PhysicalDrive access and I would not be surprised if that were the case here as well.